# Java: cannot find symbol when files are in same folder

Tags: java, compiler-errors, package, cannot-find-symbol

I created a file Organ.java

```
package OrganProject;

public class Organ{

    private String name;
    private String condition;

    public Organ(String name, String condition){

        this.name = name;
        this.condition = condition;

    }

    public String getName(){
        return this.name;
    }

    public String getCondition(){
        return this.condition;
    }

    public void setName(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setCondition(String condition){
        this.condition = condition;
    }

    public void display(){
        System.out.println("Name: " + this.getName());
        System.out.println("Condition: " + this.getCondition());
    }
}
```

however, when I call this class in Main.java

```
package OrganProject;
public class Main { 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Organ organ = new Organ("eye", "good");
        organ.display();
    }
}
```

There was an error showing that

```
Main.java:7: error: cannot find symbol
        Organ organ = new Organ("eye", "good");
        ^
  symbol:   class Organ
  location: class Main
Main.java:7: error: cannot find symbol
        Organ organ = new Organ("eye", "good");
                          ^
  symbol:   class Organ
  location: class Main
2 errors
```

The 2 files are all in the same folder called OrganProject; however, they seem unable to interlink each other. May I ask what is the reason behind it and how to resolve this problem?

I had tried to create new folder and move the files into that new folder, hope can refresh the compile, however, it did not work.

Comment: Please, [do not upload images of code/data/error](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557).

Comment: Show us the other file. Then comment here once you edited your question.

Comment: How exactly are you compiling the classes?

Comment: @davidalayachew I have re-edited my question

Comment: @Jesper I dont actually know what is compiling in Java. Do you meant the directories of the files? I put both the Main.java & Organ.java under OrganProject folder.

Comment: I have answered your question. Let me know via comment (on my answer) if it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your terminal, make a folder called `OrganProject`, then put your 2 files into there. Then, ***go outside the folder*** and call the following command in that terminal.

```
javac OrganProject/Main.java OrganProject/Organ.java
```

This compiles your code, creating corresponding `.class` files. Then, while still being immediately outside of the `OrganProject` folder, call the following command in that terminal too.

```
java OrganProject/Main
```

This will actually run the code. When I run your code, this is what I get.

```
Name: eye
Condition: good
```

Comment: Hi!!! Thank you so much for your suggestion. My codes worked after using ur method. However, if I stop using **javac** in the terminal, and choose to run the ```Main.java``` file in VScode, the same error comes along.

Comment: @ling131031003 I am glad it worked. And yes, that makes sense why it doesn't work. If you want, you can run the commands I showed you in VSCode's terminal. That should work just fine as well.

Comment: But remember, in Java, you are always supposed to compile your code before running it. `javac` is the command that compiles code, and `java` is the command that runs it. So, if you do not call `javac`, then you will not be able to run your code. That said, if your code is only in 1 file, and not 2 or more, then you can get away with just calling `java` on your `Main.java`. In the near future, they are actually going to let you get away with running multiple files without compiling them. Here is a link to that project proposal. https://openjdk.org/jeps/8304400

Comment: And please note, if the version of Java you are running is Java 11 or later, then that explains why you are running into the problem you did. They have not yet released the ability to run ***multiple*** files without compiling, but Java 11 is when they released the ability to run a ***single*** file without compiling. Here is a link to the single file source code proposal. https://openjdk.org/jeps/8304400 -- Notice how they restrict this ability to a single file. And notice how the previous link I sent you talks about how they intend to deal with the exact problem you are describing.

Comment: Thank you!!! I really appreciate your help! It really helps me a lot as I was bothered by this problem for quite a long time. Anyways, thank you so much again for your kindness.

Comment: Anytime. Let me know if you run into more issue with this. And if any of the answers here helped you, be sure to upvote them, and checkmark the one that solved your problem.